# Loaded object is apparently null after contentLoaderInfo's Event.complete function has run?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am having an issue with a class I'm working on. I currently load an image as a bitmap and store its data into regState:BitmapData so that I may make new instances of that image later on.  When I test if I can use the loaded data at a later time with my newBitmapIntance() function, it says that regState is null.  I'm lost as to why this is the case, since it works flawlessly to create an instance of itself in my loadContent() function.  Any way I can successfully hold on to my loaded bitmapdata for later use?

Class so far For reference:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;

    public class MyObj extends MovieClip
    {
        private var regState:BitmapData;

        public function MyObj() 
        {

        }
        public function loadImage(url:String):void
        {
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            var imgLdr:Loader = new Loader();
            imgLdr.load(urlRequest);
            imgLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadContent);
        }

        private function setRegState(temp:BitmapData):void
        {
            this.regState = temp.clone();
        }
        public function getRegState():BitmapData
        {
            return this.regState;
        }

        private function loadContent(event:Event)
        {
            var temp:Bitmap = event.target.content as Bitmap;
            this.setRegState(temp.bitmapData);

            this.addChild(newBitmapIntance());
        }

        public function newBitmapIntance():Bitmap
        {
            var temp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(this.getRegState());

            return temp;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactored MyObj:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class MyObj extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _bitmapData:BitmapData;

        public function loadImage(url:String):void
        {
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            var imgLdr:Loader = new Loader();
            imgLdr.load(urlRequest);
            imgLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadContent);
        }

        public function clone():MovieClip
        {
            var newClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            newClip.addChild( new Bitmap( _bitmapData.clone() ) );
            return newClip;
        }

        public function MyObj() 
        {

        }

        private function loadContent(event:Event):void
        {
            this._bitmapData = Bitmap(event.target.content).bitmapData;
            this.dispatchEvent( new Event( "imageLoaded" ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Use it from another class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        private var _factory:MyObj;

        public function Test()
        {
            _factory = new MyObj();
            _factory.loadImage( "test.jpg" );
            _factory.addEventListener( "imageLoaded", imageLoaderHandler );
        }

        private function imageLoaderHandler( e:Event ):void
        {
            var one:MovieClip = _factory.clone();

            this.addChild( one );

            var two:MovieClip = _factory.clone();
            two.x = 100;
            two.y = 100;

            this.addChild( two );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still have the same error even if I make urlRequest, imgLdr,and temp variables of the class and assign imgLdr.content accordingly.  It seems as if the reference to the loaded data is there but the data itself is gone no matter what I do.

Comment: If you use the class above like this what traces out? 
`var myObj:MyObj = new MyObj();
   myObj.loadImage( "test.jpg" );
   var bitmap:Bitmap = myObj.newBitmapIntance();
   trace(bitmap);`

Comment: I'm getting an empty movie clip in my test rather than a null reference error.  Tracing produces [object Bitmap].  I appreciate all the help so far btw.

Comment: Ok, I think you're trying to have that MovieClip be a holder for the loaded bitmap right? If so retry the code I edited above.

Comment: I'm sorry, let me re-explain. Your code before worked fine for the object itself, but calling myObj.newBitmapIntance() for a new movieclip did not work.

Comment: Are you wanting the MyObj class to be a 'factory' for creating a bunch of other movieclips?

Comment: Kinda yeah the reason it extends MovieClip was just so I could test it in a different contex.  I think the problem may be on my end because it seems to me that your code is fine.

Comment: I had another thought the issue might be that you're trying to use MyObj's bitmap data before the image has loaded? If that's the case you'd want MyObj to dispatch an event and then have another class (or the root) listen and respond to the event.

Comment: Yes it appears that is the issue! What I thought was loaded apparently was not.  What is the org.osmf.events.TimeEvent library?  I cannot seem to implement it. Is it the open source media framework?

Comment: Great! Woops `import org.osmf.events.TimeEvent;` was because I was using a Timer to test stuff and I imported it rather than a regular TimerEvent by mistake (osmf = Adobe's Open Source Media Framework)

Comment: Thanks for all the help if I had enough rep to upvote you I would.  I accepted your answer as well.  Have a good one!